# Can't access a global variable inside a function in elisp?

Tags: variables, symbols, error

I am trying to make a simple function that toggles "lsp-ui-doc-show" and "lsp-ui-doc-hide", by calling the same function every time.

Thought it was simple enough to use a global variable, call the command and then modify the same variable from inside the function.

Here is the code:

```
(defvar lsp-ui-doc-toggle 1)

(defun toggle-lsp-ui-doc ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq lsp-ui-doc-toggle 1)
      (call-interactively 'lsp-ui-doc-show)
    (set lsp-ui-doc-toggle 2)
      )
  (if (eq lsp-ui-doc-toggle 2)
      (call-interactively 'lsp-ui-doc-hide)
    (set lsp-ui-doc-toggle 1)
    )
  )
```

The error I receive is `if: Wrong type argument: symbolp, 1`. Now, I might misunderstand the error, but I believe it comes from line 4, where I'm trying to make the comparison, right?

Does that mean I can't access `lsp-ui-doc-toggle` inside the function? I have also tried to define the variable with `setq`, tried to make the comparison with `equal`, `=`, nothing works.

Can anybody please help me understand what's going on?

**Edit:**

I did it. I'll post the working code here, in case it will help somebody.

As Drew answered, the error came from `set`, but I also had other issues in my code:

1. The `if` condition doesn't accept multiple statements so I had to use `cond` instead.
2. Both `if` conditions were executed one after the other, because the variable was changed to `2` by the first, which allowed the second to start. I had to use a `catch/throw` to end the function after changing the variable in the first condition.

```
(defvar lspDocSwitch 1)

(defun toggleLspDoc ()
  (interactive)
  (catch 'return
    (cond ((eq lspDocSwitch 1)
       (call-interactively 'lsp-ui-doc-show)
       (setq  lspDocSwitch 2)
       (throw 'return "End function")
       )
      )
    (cond ((eq lspDocSwitch 2)
       (setq lspDocSwitch 1)
       (call-interactively 'lsp-ui-doc-hide)
       )
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: You do *not* need a `catch/throw` and you do *not* need two `cond`s: you need a single `cond` that tests two different conditions and does some things for each of the possible conditions - and that's it. See the description of `cond` and pay attention to the example in the [Introduction to Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Recursion-with-cond.html) manual which you should read in its entirety.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from these lines:

```lisp
(set lsp-ui-doc-toggle 2)

(set lsp-ui-doc-toggle 1)
```

You want `setq`, not `set`.  Function `set` expects a symbol, and it evaluates its arguments.  So it evaluates variable `lsp-ui-doc-toggle` hoping to get a symbol to use as a variable (setting **its** value).

Comment: Thank you, that error was making me mad! I also had other issues in the code, but I got it eventually. I'll edit the post with the working code.